# Can Python 3.2 run on Windows 2000?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project and I want to use python but the server is only Windows Server 2000 can it run on this system?

Comment: Run the complete test suite and see if passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using windows 2000 then it's possible that python 3.2 is not your best alternative.
A couple of months ago there was an interesting thread in the python-dev mailing list[1] about dropping win2k support (there are some annoying bugs for this platform).

[1] http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-March/098074.html

Comment: How about version 2.7 of Python then?

Comment: I'm not really sure about 2.7, I did a little "internet research" and couldn't find a solid reference regarding problems between python 2.7 and win 2k. I think the best option is to install python 2.7 and run some tests (i.e. run some "heavy" python apps and check everything works A_OK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Micro Python](https://micropython.org/) for DOS. It has Python 3.4 syntax.